# Reg expression validate / \ # & characters

Tags: regex

I've been learning how Regular expressions work, which is very tricky for me. I would like to validate this chars below from input field. Basically if string contains any of these characters, `alert('bad chars')`

1. /
2. \
3. #
4. &

I found this code, but when I change it around doesn't seem to work.  How can I alter this code to meet my needs?

```
var str = $(this).val();
if(/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/.test(str) == false) {
    alert('bad');
    return false;
} else {
    alert('good');
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by validate, ensure they exist, ensure they don't exist, contain a certain amount, contain all, contain in certain order, etc.

Comment: Here's a reference to help understand regex code. [Google Regex Explainer.](http://regex-explain.googlecode.com/hg/explain.html#^[a-zA-Z0-9-%20]*%24)

Comment: Basically if string contains these chars alert('bad chars')

Comment: What are you _actually_ trying to accomplish?  Do you want the 'bad' alert to only happen if the string contains those specific characters ('/','\','#','&')? Or do you want to alert when _any_ non-alphanumeric (non-alphabet and non-number) character is entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/` means the following:

- `^` the string MUST start here
- `[a-zA-Z0-9- ]` a letter between `a` and `z` upper or lower case, a number between `0` and `9`, dashes (`-`) and spaces.
- `*` repeated 0 or more times
- `$` the string must end here.

In the case of "any character but" you can use `^` like so: `/^[^\/\\#&]*$/`. If this matches true, then it doesn't have any of those characters. `^` right after a `[` means *match anything that isn't the following*.

.

Answer (score 1):

You could just try the following:

```
if("/[\\/#&]/".test(str) == true) {
    alert('bad');
    return false;
} else {
    alert('good');
}
```

**NOTE:** I'm not 100% on what characters need to be escaped in JavaScript vs. .NET regular expressions, but basically, I'm saying if your string contains any of the characters `\`, `/`, `#` or `&`, then alert 'bad'.

Comment: [Javascript](http://regex-explain.googlecode.com/hg/explain.html#[\\/%23%26]) only requires `\` to be escaped.

Comment: and of course, the `\ ` didn't show up because it needed to be escaped... Javascript requires that the character `\ ` be escaped.

Comment: @Enigmadan: You know, I thought that character needed to be escaped! :) Hehe.... Thanks again.